# Django Urls - two views with same regular expression

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

I have two views with the same regular expression, as you can see below. It's a Category and an Article view, their entry slugs will never be the same so it should be no problem. But at the moment it doesn't work well, as you prolly know the category-view will get triggered.

*Please do not suggest to make the url structure unique, the slugs of categories and articles will never be the same. It should be as short as possible.*

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index', index.Index.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^search', search.Index.as_view(), name='search'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>.+)$', category.Index.as_view(), name='category'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>.+)$', article.Index.as_view(), name='article'),
]
```

I tried to reverse from views.category back to urls.py if there is no category to find like this:

**views.category.py**

```
class Index(View):
    def get(self, request, slug):
        category = CategoryModel.objects.get(slug=slug)
        if category is None:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('article', args=[slug]))

        context = {
            'category': category
        }
        return render(request, 'category/index.html', context)
```

**The error** (but there is a article with slug 'test123'):

```
NoReverseMatch at /wiki/test123
Reverse for 'article' with arguments '('test123',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Using Python 3.6

Comment: You will have a much easier time if you do not do this and instead make your URLs unambiguous.

Comment: That's exactly not what I want, but thanks anyway.

Comment: I think you may not understand what you're asking the router to do. How is it supposed to tell the difference between a category and an article with only the text?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try differentiating the URLs like so

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index', index.Index.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^search', search.Index.as_view(), name='search'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<slug>.+)$', category.Index.as_view(), name='category'),
    url(r'^article/(?P<slug>.+)$', article.Index.as_view(), name='article'),
]
```

You get to use the same regular expressions without the URL being ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `article.Index` view and rather than trying to redirect when there's no object for `Category`, you can call the method you defined in `article.Index` with the same parameters as the `get` method takes in `article.Index` view.

**Example**:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^index', index.Index.as_view(), name='index'),
  url(r'^search', search.Index.as_view(), name='search'),
  url(r'^(?P<slug>.+)$', category.Index.as_view(), name='category'),
  # article url removed
]
```

views.category.py

```
from path.to.article import Index as ArticleIndexView

class Index(View):
    def get(self, request, slug):
        category = CategoryModel.objects.get(slug=slug)
        if category is None:
            # calling article app's Index get method
            article_index_view_obj = ArticleIndexView()
            return article_index_view_obj.get(request, slug)

        context = {
            'category': category
        }
        return render(request, 'category/index.html', context)
```

If you make the `article.Index` class view as function-based view.
You can import `from path.to.article import index as article_index`
and then, instead of instantiating the object, you can directly call `article_index(request, slug)`.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I found but I thought its maybe possible to solve this with two different View files.

Comment: Yeah, you can then instantiate the `article.Index` view and call the `get` method on that created instance or use function based view which you can easier than the class-based one.

Comment: Yes sorry I guess I dont understand

Comment: Doesnt work. I guess its because its a as_view() class

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here.

(1) You call `reverse` with `args` but you have specified a `kwarg`.

```
if category is None:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('article', args=[slug]))
```

> Reverse for 'article' with arguments '('test123',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Says exactly that - as you did not provide the keyword argument, it could not find the matching URL pattern. This would be correct:

```
if category is None:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('article', kwargs={'slug':slug}))
```

(2) You will end up in that same code again and again - is what I expect to happen once you fix (1). Because if `reverse` really does reverse the URL - the result of `reverse` will of course also match the `category` URL which means it will simply call the `category.Index` view - again.

I think your URL setup could actually work because the resolver does try all URLs sequentially until one comes along that matches. I'm just not sure if you can make the view return something that will lead to the URL resolver to kick in and decide to take the next URL (`article`) instead of `category` which just resolved. Probably not.

In this case, if you are fine with redirects, you could just define 3 URL patterns. 1 for the view that will operate as a switch and redirect to the CategoryView or ArticleView respectively.

Otherwise go with Sachin Kukreja's solution of handling both in one view.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it like this. Actually I wanna use 2 different views but I guess it's fine too. Does someone see a mistake?

```
class Index(View):
    def get(self, request, slug):
        self.request = request
        self.slug = slug
        self.item = None
        is_article = ArticleModel.objects.filter(slug=self.slug).exists()

        if is_article:
            self.item = 'article'
            return self.article()

        is_category = CategoryModel.objects.filter(slug=self.slug).exists()
        if is_category:
            self.item = 'category'
            return self.category()

        self.item = None
        # 404 here
        return HttpResponse(self.item)

    def article(self):
        article = ArticleModel.objects.get(slug=self.slug)
        context = {
            'article': article
        }
        return render(self.request, 'article/index.html', context)

    def category(self):
        category = CategoryModel.objects.get(slug=self.slug)
        context = {
            'category': category
        }
        return render(self.request, 'article/index.html', context)
```